# Python - read comma delimited file into array

Tags: python

I want to read a file that has data:

```
    IAGE0,IAGE5,IAGE15,IAGE25,IAGE35,IAGE45,IAGE55
    5,5,5.4,4.2,3.8,3.8,3.8
    4.3,4.3,4.9,3.4,3,3.7,3.7
    3.6,3.6,4.2,2.9,2.7,3.5,3.5
    3,3,3.6,2.7,2.7,3.3,3.3
    2.7,2.7,3.2,2.6,2.8,3.1,3.1
    2.4,2.4,3,2.6,2.9,3,3
```

So I want an array "iage0[1]" to read "5 and "iage15[1]=5.4".  The header can be skipped.  Then iage0[2] = 4.3 etc... for each row.  So an array is just a column.

I thought "f.readlines(3)" would read line 3, but it seems to still read the first line.  Somehow I need to split the line into separate values.

Here is my code, I don't know how to split up the "content" or read the next line.  Sorry for the simple question but I just started coding yesterday.

```
def ReadTxtFile():
    with open("c:\\jeff\\vba\\lapseC2.csv", "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines(3)
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` 
    content = [x.strip() for x in content] 
    print("Done")
    print(content)
```

Comment: You might want to look into `numpy` or `pandas` for this

Comment: f.readlines()[3] reads the line not f.readlines(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is similar to what you're looking for. (Python 3.6)

```
import csv

d = {}
headers = []
with open('data.csv') as file_obj:
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj)
    for header in next(reader):
        headers.append(header)
        d[header] = []
    for line in reader:
        for idx,element in enumerate(line):
            d[headers[idx]].append(element)

print(d)
{'IAGE0': ['5', '4.3', '3.6', '3', '2.7', '2.4'], 'IAGE5': ['5', '4.3', '3.6', '3', '2.7', '2.4'], 'IAGE15': ['5.4', '4.9', '4.2', '3.6', '3.2', '3'], 'IAGE25': ['4.2', '3.4', '2.9', '2.7', '2.6', '2.6'], 'IAGE35': ['3.8', '3', '2.7', '2.7', '2.8', '2.9'], 'IAGE45': ['3.8', '3.7', '3.5', '3.3', '3.1', '3'], 'IAGE55': ['3.8', '3.7', '3.5', '3.3', '3.1', '3']}
print(d['IAGE0'][0])
5
print(d['IAGE15'][0])
5.4
```

You can also use DictReader

```
d = {}
headers = []
with open('data.csv') as file_obj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj)
    for line in reader:
        for key,value in line.items():
            if key not in d:
                d[key] = [value]
            else:
                d[key].append(value)


print(d)
{'IAGE0': ['5', '4.3', '3.6', '3', '2.7', '2.4'], 'IAGE5': ['5', '4.3', '3.6', '3', '2.7', '2.4'], 'IAGE15': ['5.4', '4.9', '4.2', '3.6', '3.2', '3'], 'IAGE25': ['4.2', '3.4', '2.9', '2.7', '2.6', '2.6'], 'IAGE35': ['3.8', '3', '2.7', '2.7', '2.8', '2.9'], 'IAGE45': ['3.8', '3.7', '3.5', '3.3', '3.1', '3'], 'IAGE55': ['3.8', '3.7', '3.5', '3.3', '3.1', '3']}
print(d['IAGE0'][0])
5
print(d['IAGE15'][0])
5.4
```

Comment: Documentation for the csv module can be found at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html there also are additional examples.